# Why is "01" == "1", "000333" == "333", etc true?

Tags: php, string-comparison

While developing a PHP application, I ran into this strange quirk.

Apparently, the string `'01' == '1'`, `'05' == '5'`, `'03111' == '3111'`.
I tried this -

```
php > $numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
php > in_array("01", $numbers);
true
php > var_dump("01" == "1");
true
php > var_dump("00003333" == "3333")
true
```

How do I prevent this (i.e return false for the `in_array` call) , and why is it happening in the first place?

Comment: use 3 equals signs `===`

Comment: PHP's manual has some guidelines on variable types and their effect in comparisons. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: FYI: `in_array()` does a loosely comparison by default, so it is basically the same as `==` and for that also the same reason why it works the same way. It also is the same solution for solving it with `==` and `in_array()` to just use identical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You should use strict comparison in in_array

```
in_array("01", $numbers, true);
```

and === instead of ==
then php compare also types